# Why are files I generate with a bash script within a docker container also saving locally?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have an aws/appium test project I want to run in docker. I have a bash script that runs in the container which downloads a file from S3 and creates a zip of my project.

The Dockerfile:

```
FROM maven:3.3.9

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get -y install python && \
    apt-get -y install python-pip && \
    pip install awscli

RUN export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin
```

There's a docker compose file, the command runs a bash script:

```
version: '2'

volumes:
    maven_cache: ~

services:
    application: &application
        build: .
        tmpfs:
            - /tmp:rw,nodev,noexec,nosuid
        volumes:
            - ./:/app
            - maven_cache:/root/.m2/repository
        working_dir: /app
        command: ./aws-upload.sh
```

This is the beginning of the ./aws-upload.sh bash script. It prepares the files I need for uploading later:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

mvn clean package -DskipTests=true

aws s3 cp s3://<bucket-name>/app.apk $(pwd)
cp target/zip-with-dependencies.zip $(pwd)
```

I only want the above files to exist within the container, however they appear locally also. Is there something in my docker-compose file that isn't configured correctly?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In your compose file you are defining a volume `./:/app` which maps the host folder where the compose file is located to the containers `app` folder. If you execute your bash script in the `app` folder it will also make the files it is creating available on the host.

If you want to avoid this either remove the volume mapping (in case you don't need it) or execute the script in another folder which is not mapped to your host.

Answer (score 0):

This is normal. When you declared the following inside the composefile:

```
volumes:
    - ./:/app
```

This means mount the current host directory onto `/app` inside the container. This will effectivelty keep the current directory and the `/app` folder inside the container in sync.

Thus if the `aws-upload.sh` script creates files in `/app`, they will also show next to the compose file.